# I shot using S3 and it's pixelated

Tags: post-processing, troubleshooting, image-quality, jpeg

I generally shoot L + Raw but this time, I was doing a shoot for a new company and for some reason thought that I could use the "S3" JPEG setting (720x480). They are using them for online. They have been emailing me and asking for changes daily and now they say when they zoom in, it's pixelated and to send the Raw files. I didn't shoot in Raw so I have no idea how to make them happy. I have changed to their dimensions of 5184X3458. I have reduced the jpeg size. I really need help here. I mostly shoot headshots and always use L +Raw for editing. I don't know why I chose S3.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: What is S3? Small filesize Number 3? Samsung gallaxy 3?

Comment: Fujifilm FinePix S3, perhaps?

Comment: S3 is the smallest size JPEG setting for many Canon cameras. For example with the EOS 5D Mark III: L is 5760x3840, M is 3840x2560, S1 is 2880x1920, S2 is 1920x1208, and S3 is 720x480.

Answer (score 7):

Bottom line is you screwed up technically, and by doing that you have delivered an inferior quality product - and most crucially one which does not meet the client's requirements. There isn't some magic you can do to recreate that data you threw away by not shooting RAW.

This job's gone - your most important concern now should be protecting your professional reputation. You can try and bluff your way out of it, but I'd put good money on you getting found out and then your professional reputation is gone. Apologise to the company and offer them their money back in full, no questions asked, and start work on finding a new client. You'll know for next time to double check that you're shooting RAW.

Comment: If the work is something that could be redone (i.e. posed headshots) then she could offer to redo the job *and* charge for neither the original work nor the makeup work. If the photos were of an event then she's pretty much limited to waiving her fee and profusely apologizing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make them happy. You took tiny images with your camera.

Largest sizes for 720x480 Pixels Image without distortion:

- 96 dpi (Flat Panel) - 7.5 inches x 5 inches
- 150 dpi (Cell Phone) - 4.8 x 3.2 inches
- 300 dpi (Laser Printed) - 2.4 x 1.6 inches

If your client wants to have an image printed or put in an advertisement, the largest is 2.4 inches x 1.6 (a business card). Might be best to give them their money back and do a complimentary shoot for good faith.